# Start and shutdown errors 12.10

Tags: startup, 12.10, shutdown

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10. I am now stuck as I don't know what to do. The installation have for some reason failed on some place as I am getting error messages on start and shutdown (restart). There were no errors during the installation though. On startup it's saying that dev/sda is an invalid argument and it takes, quite long, time for it to come right and start normal. On shutdown it won't show the old screen but you see the processes made. It also contains an error and it's talking about shutting down and about Apache. I installed through the update manager on Ubuntu 12.04 and I had all updates made before downloading and have several times tried to update the new version but there is nothing to update.

My files are important to me, though at the currently I could unistall all my programs and only loose some time. Does anyone have this problem, please leave a comment and tell me your experience and if you have a ansver how to fix my issues please help.

Thank you.

//Viktor

Comment: "dev/sda invalid argument" sounds like a problem with fstab. Could you post the output of `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: What do you mean by "post the output of cat /etc/fstab"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also upgraded from 12.04. The best bet would be in my opinion to do a clean install. I am running a dual-boot on both my desktop and laptop. I will just do a clean install and this was referenced somewhere else to me by another member. Some things get messed up while upgrading, I knew this was going to happen.

Comment: Unless Viktor has his /home on a separate partition a clean install would overwrite file and cause data loss. Not saying it isn't an option, just be aware.